# What is the integral of a family of diffusion processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $S$ be an infinite subset of $[0,1]$.
For all $s \in S$, let W_s(t) be a standard Wiener process.

Definite P(s)_t = \mu(P,s,t) dt + \sigma(P,s,t) dW^s_t

Can we characterize?
$$F_t= \int_S P(s)_t ds$$

Comment: Your notation here seems rather nonstandard. Can you elaborate somewhat? It sounds like you are running an infinite collection of standard Wiener processes and then somehow integrating all of them, but it is not at all clear how the Wiener processes relate or how your integration proceeds.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why the law of large numbers would apply.

Comment: Basically I have an infinite number of Wiener processes indexed by $s$. 

And define diffusion processes
$$S_t(s) = \int_0^t \mu(t,S_t,s) dt + \int_0^t \sigma(t,S_t,s) dWt$$ 
And my guess is that
$$F=\int_S S_t(s) ds$$ should only have a drift component

Comment: @Ian, you got it exactly right. In principle the processes could have any relation. But you can assume they are independent if that facilitates matters. The integration is over an arbitrary subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JamieLannister my intuition is that at any instant $t$ you are sort of drawing an infinite amount of draws from a normal distribution. Assuming that $dW_t$ behaves sort of like a normal distribution. And the law of large number should tell you that the sum of the draws goes to zero as the number of draws goes to infinity. But as you see rigor is completely absent in the argument.

Comment: In which sense do you think the integral $F$ could be well defined?

Comment: @Did, very good point.
I guess $F$ could be infinite (was that your concern?).
What about introducing a probability measure $g$ and defining,
$$G = \int_S g(s) S_t(s) ds $$
Then is all $S_t(s)$ are finite, $G$ should be finite.
Would I be safe to compute the variance of $G$?

Comment: No, infinities are not the main concern here, rather the definition of the integral you have in mind. Note that if $(X_t)$ is i.i.d. (and not some Dirac distribution), then the integral $$\int_0^1X_tdt$$ simply does not exist.

Comment: @Did I elaborate on the problem here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204330/can-we-integrate-over-an-infinite-collection-of-wiener-processes
I would very much appreciate if you had a look

Comment: Since you now asked basically twice (here) plus once (on math.overflow) the same question, and you received the same answer each time (object does not exist), the time might be ripe for you to indicate some reliable sources where objects similar to the ones you have in mind are defined/used.

Comment: @Did, thanks for all the feedback. The several versions of the question were just attempts to clarify the question.
I am trying to follow this lectures notes: http://www.eco.uc3m.es/~mkredler/ContTime/KolmForwEqu.pdf
To derive a Kolmogorov Forward (or Fokker-Planck) Equation. On the second bullet point of page two he states "the brownian motion term will be zero for each x" I guess that relies on some law of large numbers type of argument in the background but I am failing to make it formal.

Comment: ...But the situation there is entirely different from what you describe in your post! As is customary, the authors assume that the Brownian motion $(W(t))_t$ does not depend on $s$ -- which is, roughly speaking, *the opposite* of drawing a new independent Brownian motion $(W_s(t))_t$ for each new value of $s$.

Comment: Thanks @Did. The conclusion is that the integral I was trying to compute is well define when the Brownian motion does not depend on $s$ and its expexted value and variance can be computed as shown by JamieLannister. Is there is a new i.i.d. draw of Brownian motion for each $s$, the integral does not exist. That answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take on this,

Let $S_t(s) = \int_0^t \mu(t,S_t,s)dt + \int_0^t \sigma(t,S_t,s)dW_t$

Then, $S_t(s)$ is a normally distributed random variable parametrized by it's expectation and variance.

To see that $S_t(s)$ is normal,

$S_t(s) = \int_0^t \mu(t,S_t,s)dt + \int_0^t \sigma(t,S_t,s)dW_t$,

which is equal to a constant $\int_0^t \mu(t,S_t,s)dt = A + \text{an infinite sum of normal random variables since } dW_t \text{ is distributed }$
$\mathcal N(0,1).$ The sum of normal random variables is again normally distributed, hence, the limit of the sum, the integral, is normally distributed by weak convergence.

$\Bbb E[S_t(s)] = \Bbb E[\int_0^t\mu(t,S_t,s)dt] + \Bbb E[\int_0^t \sigma(t,S_t,s)dW_t]$

$= \int_0^t\mu(t,S_t,s)dt + \int_0^t \sigma(t,S_t,s)\Bbb E[dW_t]$

Where we are able to pass the Expectation operator under the integral by dominated convergence because the integral is a limit of sums, so we can pass the expectation operator through the integral. Also assuming that $\sigma(t,S_t,s)$ is deterministic.

$\Rightarrow \Bbb E[S_t(s)] = \int_0^t\mu(t,S_t,s)dt$ Because $\Bbb E[dW_t] = 0$

Similarly,

$\Bbb E[S_t(s)^2] = \Bbb E[(\int_0^t \sigma(t,S_t,s)dW_t)^2] = \int_0^t \Bbb E[\sigma(t,S_t,s)^2dW_t^2]$ By Ito Isometry.

$\Rightarrow \Bbb E[S_t(s)^2] = \int_0^t \Bbb E[\sigma(t,S_t,s)^2dt] = \int_0^t \sigma(t,S_t,s)^2dt \Rightarrow Var(S_t(s)) = \Bbb E[S_t(s)^2] - \Bbb E[S_t(s)]^2$

I hope that's what you were asking.

Comment: It is not exactly what I am asking. I am asking about the variance of $F$, where 
$$F= \int_S S_t(s) ds$$

Comment: Same idea, this is again normally distributed. You can pass the Expectation under the integral. And, you can exploit mean square convergence to find the second moment of *F* by finding $\int_S \Bbb E[(S_t(s)ds)^2]$ calculated before. Then, computing the variance follows.

Comment: If you simulate it, and compute, your result will be close.

Comment: What you're looking for is called Ito Isometry.